# Term used for the final work of an artist before their death

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name given for the final painting of an artist before they die?

For example:

> It was his _______.
>
> This painting was his _______.

Comment: Maybe his ***ultimate*** work?  Certainly it would be that under one definition of *ultimate*

Comment: Unfinished is pretty well established.

Comment: @PhilSweet But, in this case, we don't know whether the work was finished or unfinished!

Answer (score 8):

A **swan song** is, according to the OED

> the last work of a poet or musician, composed shortly before his death; hence, any final performance, action, or effort.

This phrase, although rather metaphorical, captures your desired meaning. It is more often applied to musicians than other artists; however, it can be used in a wider sense.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly informal option is **last hurrah**, though Merriam-Webster doesn't give it this tag.

> a final, often valedictory effort, production, or appearance

[From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%20hurrah?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

> A final act, performance, or effort.

[From Oxford Dictionaries.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/last_hurrah)

The adjective *valedictory* literally means 'a farewell', so this fits nicely.  Also, the term can apply to pretty much anyone, so there's no specificity.

Answer (score 1):

[***Finale***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/finale) means "final composition". It is among the many ways to refer to a painter's last work. ***Parting [expression](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/expression)***, ***final [piece](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/piece)***, ***[consummate](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/consummate) representation***, and ***[ultimate](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ultimate) [rendering](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rendering)*** all capture the idea of the final painting.

An example:

> This painting was his **ultimate rendering**.
> It was his **parting expression**.